# In Julia, is there a macro to determine whether an expression can be evaluated at parse time?

Tags: performance, static, julia

In many situations I would like to be able to assert that a value is not evaluated at run-time. For example, when constructing some parametrized struct `Foo{A} where {A}`, I would like to make sure that `A` is known at parse time and must not be determined through dynamic dispatch.  E.g. something like `Foo{@isstatic A}()`.

Is there a way to enforce that?

**Update 1:**

Maybe the thing that I want is checking whether the type is `Core.Compiler.Const` (e.g. through a type assertion)? But I doubt that this is the right thing to do here.

**Update 2:**

Maybe another way to phrase this: Is there something like the C++ `constexpr` in Julia that is intended to be used outside of Base?

Comment: Almost all cases in Julia when you need process something depending on type at the compile time can be solved using the @generated macro. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: One example where I would want to use something like this if I have some "hard coded" constant that is a parameter for some structs (e.g. the length of a static array). In cpp I can be very explicit about this by: I define some `constexpr k` within my function and use it as template-argument in various places. In Julia, if I define a variable `k` that I use as parameter to some constructor or function call I may accidentally make things type unstable if the compiler fails to figure out that it is a compile time constant. Value types would be an option but they are very annoying to work with.

Comment: Have a look at StaticArrays.jl API and source code and how they handle such constants coded into types. Regarding the type stability and compiler efficiency, the beauty if Julia is that you do not have to put that type of info everywhere. However writing type stable code is sometimes hard. `@code_warntype` macro is your best friend here. However the best reading is https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to enforce that on the compiler. However, nothing is ever computed in the parser (propagation of constants such as types happens at a later stage), so that's also trivial, just set it to always return `false`.

Unlike some other languages, Julia doesn't make optimizer failures (such as the inability to constant fold something) into a compiler error. It also doesn't have distinct compile time types. Everything in the language is available at runtime, so you're not beholden to the whims of some compiler standard to define what is valid at compile time and what will fail to type-check.

Rather than seeing this as a problem, embrace the fact that `Foo{@isstatic A}()` is just written `Foo{A}()` in Julia! No need for any contortions on your part! If some value is available at compile time, the compiler will figure out and use the value. If it's not known, then the runtime will still use the value to get the same answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the fact, that I don't *have* to put an annotation because the compiler will (hopefully) figure it out. But coming from a C++ background where I can be very explicit about these things just makes me (overly) convervative. The more Julia code I write and the more outputs of `@code_warntype` I look at, my trust in the compiler grows. However, in some really performance critical inner loops, I want to see an error if something like this has to be figured out at runtime. But maybe this is mostely premature optimization.